# Python type conversion error

Tags: string, python-3.x, typeerror

Am trying to print a given result using the `str.format()` in python but I keep running into an TypeError. Here is my current piece of code that gives me the error:

```
def Restaurant_calorie_average(rest):
    result = []
    for item in rest.menu:
        result.append(item.calories)
    return sum(result)/len(rest.menu)

def Restaurant_str(self: Restaurant) -> str:
return (
    "Name:     " + self.name + "\n" +
    "Cuisine:  " + self.cuisine + "\n" +
    "Phone:    " + self.phone + "\n" +
    "Menu:     " + Menu_str(self.menu) +  "\n"+
    "\t  Average Price: {0:3.2f}.  Average calories {1:}: ".format(Restaurant_price_average(self), str(Restaurant_calorie_average(self))) + "\n\n")

def Collection_str(C: list) -> str:
''' Return a string representing the collection
'''
s = ""
if not C:
    return ''
else:
    for r in C:
        s = s + Restaurant_str(r)
    return s
```

This is the error I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sage\workspace\hello\restaurantsg.py", line 229, in <module>
    restaurants()
  File "C:\Users\Sage\workspace\hello\restaurantsg.py", line 19, in restaurants
    our_rests = handle_commands(our_rests)
  File "C:\Users\Sage\workspace\hello\restaurantsg.py", line 48, in handle_commands
    print(Collection_str(C))
  File "C:\Users\Sage\workspace\hello\restaurantsg.py", line 176, in Collection_str
    s = s + Restaurant_str(r)
  File "C:\Users\Sage\workspace\hello\restaurantsg.py", line 84, in Restaurant_str
    "\tAverage Price: {0:3.2f}.  Average calories: {1:}".format(Restaurant_price_average(self), Restaurant_calorie_average(self)) + "\n\n")
  File "C:\Users\Sage\workspace\hello\restaurantsg.py", line 113, in Restaurant_calorie_average
    return float(sum(result)/len(rest.menu))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

What I don't understand is, that another function `Restaurant_price_average()` in my program has the exact same parameters and returns a float like the `Restaurant_calorie_average()` and it works just fine in the current program if I remove the `Restaurant_calorie_average()` part. I tried type converting 'Restaurant_calorie_average()`into string, putting float in format {1:3.1f}`  but it still doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me with this? The full program is here [Rprogram](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B12K4C_ZJog4eE91T0FxRDBaUFk/view?usp=sharing)  for your reference.

Comment: This is some pretty peculiar code. I recommend using actual classes instead of namedtuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the items in the `result` list have strings as `calories` and not numbers (at least some of them). The `sum()` function can't work like that because it internally adds the elements to 0, which results in the error you see:

```
In [1]: sum(['42'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-86653ad6b5d8> in <module>()
----> 1 sum(['42'])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

In [2]: sum([1, 2, '42'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c2f90238e02a> in <module>()
----> 1 sum([1, 2, '42'])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

The error is not related to the `.format()` call, because, as you can see in the traceback, it happens inside `Restaurant_calorie_average`.

You should fix your code (not shown in the question) so that `rest.menu` items only contain numbers in their `calories` attribute. Looking at your full code, apparently this part needs to be fixed:

```
def Dish_get_info() -> Dish:
    """ Prompt user for fields of Dish; create and return.
    """
    return Dish(
        input("Please enter the Dish's name:  "),
        float(input("Please enter the price of that dish:  ")),
        input("Please enter the calories in the food:  ") # <-- you are not converting
                                                          # to float here
        )
```

---

As a side note, I agree with Kevin's comment that you would have much more readable code if you wrote actual classes with methods, rather than functions. And if you do use functions, it's a widely adopted convention that function names start with lowercase letters.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That was a dumb mistake.